# leaflet plotting entire country without coordinate information

Tags: r, leaflet

I wanted to know how to plot/map country level data using leaflet. Meaning that I want to shade countries and not specific data points

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
Country  carssold    car
France   1M          Ford
Italy    0.5M        Toyota
France   0.2M        Honda
Italy    0.3M        VW
```

I want to plot in leaflet by shading those countries and showing that info for each country but leaflet doesnt recognize the geographic location without lng and lat metrics